# How to import file from parent folder in python?

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
-> d:
   -> project Main (folder)
     -> my_file.py
        -> class (My_Class_1)
        -> class (My_class_2)
     -> Folder_one 
        -> my_folder_one_file.py
```

Hai. I want to import the My_class_1 and My_class_2   into my_folder_one_file.py

try the following :

`from project Main.my_file import *`

but, I get the following error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have a file called `my_file.py` which contains a class `My_Main_Class`, and that class has three modules inside of it? That's what your diagram says right now. But modules *are* files in Python, and they certainly can't be contained inside of classes.

Comment: What is `project Main` exactly?  Do you have a folder literally named that, including the space?

Comment: @Community,@silvio mayolo , edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, its highly likely to one of the below:

- sys.path needs to be append with the module available path, pls check this
  https://linuxhint.com/sys-path-append-python/
- imported the unavailable module
- module is not installed [not in this case]

Please try sharing the "pwd" command's output from the module path.